# Change AssemblyBuilder ImageRuntimeVersion

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to dynamically create an assembly that targets a different runtime from the current AppDomain.

For example, from within a .NET 4.0 application I want to create a new assembly that targets .NET 2.0 instead.

```
AssemblyBuilder builder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var version = builder.ImageRuntimeVersion; //"v4.0.30319"
```

Answer (score 7):

If it still needed I found the following example:

[MSDN Blog- Targeting the .NET 2 Framework when using AssemblyBuilder under .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2010/07/02/targeting-the-net-2-framework-when-using-assemblybuilder-under-net-4.aspx)

Seems like you have to use the CLR native API.

Comment: That looks great. I`ll try it out when I am back at work in Jan. If it works will accept the answer.

Comment: Did this end up working? It's not marked as the answer so either it's been forgotten about, or it didn't work. I have a situation where I've written a tool which uses features from .net 4.0, that is generating a library for a framework which is only .net 2.0, so I need to be able to target the older framework.